# How to restore the hidden wpf window from process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ipc

In my wpf window I hides the window and remove it from task bar on close.

How I can activate that window from running process. I have tried many ways but no success.

Here is my sample code to activate hidden window.

```
private void checkIfProcessRunning()
{           
    // get the name of our process
    string proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
    // get the list of all processes by that name
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc);
    // if there is more than one process...
    if (processes.Length > 1)
    {
    // Assume there is our process, which we will terminate, 
    // and the other process, which we want to bring to the 
    // foreground. This assumes there are only two processes 
    // in the processes array, and we need to find out which 
    // one is NOT us.
    RzLogger.WriteLine("process are running count:" + processes.Length);
        // get our process
        Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        int n = 0;        // assume the other process is at index 0
                          // if this process id is OUR process ID...
        if (processes[0].Id == p.Id)
        {
        RzLogger.WriteLine("other process are at 1");
        // then the other process is at index 1
        n = 1;
        }
        // get the window handle
        IntPtr hWnd = processes[n].MainWindowHandle;
    RzLogger.WriteLine("main handle is:" + hWnd);
        // if iconic, we need to restore the window
        if (IsIconic(hWnd))
        {
        RzLogger.WriteLine("is minimized");
        ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

    }
    // bring it to the foreground
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    // exit our process
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
    return;
    }
    // ... continue with your application initialization here.

}
```

The problem is I am getting handle as 0 always.

Is there a way to do this? and I don't want to show anything in taskbar

Comment: Are you talking about the WPF windows in your own process? Or what windows are you trying restore?

Comment: YOu could use interprocess messages to connect to your other instance and tell it to unhide - [pipe messageing on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication). Essentially you create a pipe server listeneing on a certain name, if your application gets started anew you use a global named mutex to check if its starteed - if so, you fire a "unhide" message and terminate yourself. By using the global mutex you do not need to query processlists at all.

Comment: @mm8 Yes WPF window

Comment: So why don' you access the windows directly?

Comment: @mm8 sorry for confusion but problem is my window is hidden and have only process in task manager. When I run same exe again I want to show the first exe and close this one.

Comment: @patrick partner can i have named pipes without server?

Comment: See the example. Your application creates a thread that runs the PipeServer alongside your application. The second instance of your app first tries to connect to a server. if none present it creates one (I am the FIRST instance). The second Instance will try to connect to the server, get a connoection, send the "Show" Command over to yoru first instance and close itself.  This is kind-of a "Singleton" for your wpf app - with some catches on RemoteServer systems. If you need to do "real" servers, have a look at the overloads of the Pipestreamcommands - you can supply an servername there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example how to use pipes.

Using a named mutex in addition to this gets rid of some problems if you start instances very fast (you might end up with more then 1 server in that case - so create a named mutex early on and if present - just send the Show() over the pipe and close.

Created from VS2017 default Wpf-Project. Compile it, start a Debug-Build, go to the output folder and start the exe again to show what it does.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="interproc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:interproc"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="tb"
                   Background="Yellow"
                   Text="..."
                   Margin="50" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace InterprocessCommunicationViaPipes
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Commands used to communiate via pipe 
    /// </summary>
    public enum EPipeCommands : byte
    {
        None, Show, Hide, Close
    };

    /// <summary>
    ///   Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml 
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Title = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Name of the pipe used for interprocess communication 
        /// </summary>
        private const string PipeName = "MyCoolApp";

        /// <summary>
        ///   prevents double Close() calls 
        /// </summary>
        private bool isClosing = false;

        /// <summary>
        ///   Server 
        /// </summary>
        private NamedPipeServerStream pipeServerStream = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///   Thread server is running in 
        /// </summary>
        private Thread ServerThread;

        void ActOnPipeCommand(EPipeCommands c)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, 
                new ThreadStart(
                delegate
                {
                    tb.Text += $"\n{DateTime.UtcNow:o} recieved {c}\n";

                    switch (c)
                    {
                        case EPipeCommands.None:
                            return;

                        case EPipeCommands.Hide:
                            Hide();
                            break;

                        case EPipeCommands.Show:
                            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

                            Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                            break;

                        case EPipeCommands.Close when !isClosing:
                            Close();
                            break;

                        case EPipeCommands.Close:
                            tb.Text += $"Already closing.\n";
                            break;

                        default:
                            tb.Text += $"Unmapped pipe action: {c.ToString()}\n";
                            break;
                    }
                }));
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   Server running? 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        bool CheckIsRunning()
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream clientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(PipeName);
            try
            {
                clientStream.Connect(1000);
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                tb.Text = $"No Server found.";
                return false;
            }

            clientStream.WriteByte((byte)EPipeCommands.Show);
            return true;
        }

        EPipeCommands InterpretePipeCommand(int v)
        {
            if (Enum.TryParse<EPipeCommands>($"{v}", out var cmd))
                return cmd;

            return EPipeCommands.None;
        }

        /// <summary> Creates the server, listens to connectiontrys, 
        /// reads 1 byte & disconnects </summary> 
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        void PipeServer(object data)
        {
            pipeServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(
                PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 
                2, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);

            do
            {
                pipeServerStream.WaitForConnection();

                if (pipeServerStream.IsConnected && !isClosing)
                {
                    ActOnPipeCommand(
                        InterpretePipeCommand(
                            pipeServerStream.ReadByte()));
                }
                pipeServerStream.Disconnect();
            }
            while (!isClosing);
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckIsRunning())
                Close();
            else
            {
                ServerThread = new Thread(PipeServer);
                ServerThread.Start();

                tb.Text = "Starting new pipe server.\n";

                Closing += (a, b) => isClosing = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```